# Mysql like clause equivalent with XPath

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt, xpath

I need the equivalent of the following sql query:

selecting all films with a title starting with 'V' followed with 3 characters and then a space followed  by a string (e.g Van Helsing)

```
SELECT * FROM films WHERE title LIKE ="V__ %";
```

How can i do this an xpath 1.0 expression in a tree like films/film/title, xpath 1.0 because i'll use php with xslt.

Thank you

Comment: Zatla00: Do note, that the currently accepted answer incorrectly selects non-matching the selection criteria elements -- see the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ok, if string after space can not be presented? Then you can use:

```
//title[starts-with(text(), 'V') and string-length(substring-before(text(), ' '))=3]
```

If presence of string after space is important, then you can use:

```
//title[starts-with(text(), 'V') and string-length(substring-before(text(), ' '))=3 and string-length(substring-after(text(), ' '))>0]
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: Thanks the second expression is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do note, that the currently accepted answer incorrectly selects non-matching the selection criteria elements -- see the end of this answer.

**Here is a correct solution**.

**Use**:

```
/films/film/title
    [starts-with(., 'V')
   and
     not(translate(substring(.,1,3), $vAlpha, ''))      
   and
     substring(.,4,1) = ' '     
   and
     not(substring(.,5,1) = ' ')
   and
     not(translate(., concat($vAlpha, ' '), ' '))       
    ]
```

where `$vAlpha` is the string consisting exactly of all letters.

**This selects all elements `/films/film/title` whose string value**:

1. Starts with the character `V`.
2. Its starting three characters are all letters.
3. Its forth character is a space.
4. Its 5th character isn't a space.
5. All of its characters are either letters or a spaces.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select=
  "concat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
          'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/films/film/title
            [starts-with(., 'V')
       and
             not(translate(substring(.,1,3), $vAlpha, ''))      
       and
             substring(.,4,1) = ' '     
           and
            not(substring(.,5,1) = ' ')
           and
            not(translate(., concat($vAlpha, ' '), ' '))        
            ]
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<films>
 <film>
  <title>Van Helsing</title>
 </film>
 <film>
  <title>Van  Helsing</title>
 </film>
 <film>
  <title>Ban Helsing</title>
 </film>
 <film>
  <title>van Helsing</title>
 </film>
 <film>
  <title>Vann Helsing</title>
 </film>
 <film>
  <title>Van Helsing2</title>
 </film>
</films>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the selected elements (only one in this case) are copied to the output**:

```
<title>Van Helsing</title>
```

**Do note, that the currently accepted answer incorrectly selects the following two not matching elements:**

```
<title>Van  Helsing</title>
<title>Van Helsing2</title>
```

Comment: great as always! But note, that xpath expression for `SELECT * FROM films WHERE title LIKE ="V__ %";` is **exactly** my first expression :)

Comment: @AlehDouhi: Yes, both answers are based on specific interpretation of what is actually wanted. Both could be closer or not so closer to the unexpressed requirements of the OP. I hope this answer provides an example of some useful techniques even if my guess of the OP's intentions isn't exactly what his unexpressed case is.

Comment: Thank you @DimitreNovatchev for your answer, it gives me the same result since the entries are alla well written, I mean film names.